# Is "studying" correct in "The students studying the hardest…"?

Tags: present-tense

I am an ESL teacher online and had this question from a student.  She said she researched it and found one grammar site that said it was correct.

> The students studying the hardest have the best results.

This seems like the incorrect tense of "studying".  Any suggestions, please??  I would have said it was incorrect but now I am unsure.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why do you have misgivings?

Comment: I do think that a relative clause sounds better there: "The students who study the hardest have the best results." But I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: You should provide more detail (what you know, what you've researched). For example, what tense do you think "studying" is in?

Comment: And the student further asked about this sentence:  The students, having studied the hardest, have the best results.  Is this correct?  I don't think it needs commas.  The student thought the sentence should use "had."  Any further help on this, please.

Comment: @Janice Are your students familiar with the difference between a "defining" and a "non-defining" phrase or clause? (Sometimes, these are also called "restrictive" and "non-restrictive" phrases/clauses.) Without commas, *having studied the hardest* would be a *defining* phrase; with them, it's a *non-defining* phrase.  Both are correct, but they have different meanings.

Comment: Also, in your second sentence, they could use *either* "have" or "had," but again the meanings will be different. "The students having studied the hardest have the best results" means that the students *now, in the present* have the best results because they studied hardest *at some time before*. "The students having studied the hardest *had* the best results" is talking about the same sequence of events (the studying still came before getting the best results) but now the whole sentence is set in the past.

Comment: @Janice Sequence of tenses: https://wwnorton.com/college/english/write/waor/CH23.pdf and difference between defining and non-defining (although the example given is for a relative clause, it's the same principle for your sentence): https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/relative_pronouns/defining_vs_non_defining.html Your students might be interested in these

Answer (score 0):

> The students studying the hardest have the best results.

Your example is fine,  as what @Michael Harvey commented.
The relative clause form as what @alphabet suggested is also fine.

[Owl.purdue.edu](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html) explains the use of participles as adjectives.

> A participle is a verbal that is used as an adjective and most often ends in -ing or -ed.

> Delores noticed her cousin **walking** along the shoreline.

> The participial phrase functions as an adjective modifying cousin.

Comment: She's asking about the *tense* it's in though?  Could you edit your answer to address that?  I think what OP is saying is that the act of "studying" *precedes* the result of "having the best results," so that it ought to be perfect tense instead of present tense.  I believe OP would consider the correct version of the sentence to be "The students *having studied* the hardest have the best results."

Comment: You might cover the usage of the **habitual present** and how that relates to "studying" in the original sentence (which is correct as-is, as you and @MichaelHarvey have noted).  "The students (who *are in the habit of*) studying the hardest have the best results..."

Comment: Thank you to everyone.  I did add another sentence that the student was struggling with -- another variation actually.  Any comments on that one?